# I can't get TcpClient to connect to a TcpListener on another host

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I have a simple client and server application that talk to each other over TCP/IP using TcpClient and TcpListener. If I run both the server and the client on the same computer with an IP address of 192.168.10.150, they can talk to each other just fine. However, if I move the client to a different computer on my home network, it can’t connect to the server any more (which is still running on 192.168.10.150). From the client computer, I can ping 192.168.10.150. I have turned off Windows Firewall on both computers. I am using port 2244, which I don’t think is used by something else. The two computers are both connected to the same wireless router. But this line of code in the client:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("192.168.10.150", 2244);
```

Throws the following exception:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond
>   192.168.10.150:2244

Both computers are running XP. Any ideas how I get these to connect?

Comment: Does you checked Firewall?

Comment: Might require port is not blocked on router firewall if it is has one

Comment: You can use a tool like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see what's going on behind the scenes to debug issues liek this. I agree with @Quintium that it might be the router firewall though.

Comment: do you by chance have the code for your TcpListener..?

Comment: Yes, how are you binding your TcpListener? IPAddress.Any?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the responses. It seems that a couple of you are correct that the network traffic was being stopped by the router. I hooked up the two computers with a switch, and they were able to talk. Unfortunately I haven't been able to successfully configure the router to allow the traffic, but that's OK, as I can just use the switch for now.